# Scrolling issue when characters are blank at the end

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, richtextbox

I'm developing a very simple application for text visualization in C # .NET Framework 4.8, but I found the following problem:

My file is loaded inside a RichTextBox, but when the text ends with white spaces, the RichTextBox scroll doesn't follow those spaces.

in the image that the horizontal scroll is already at the end and only shows up to the "." character. To show the rest I have to move the cursor through the keyboard arrows like in the second image:

[image]

[image]

And if I open the file in others text editors like note pad for example,
I don't need to move the cursor to see that there are spaces at the end of the line:

[image]

I change the Control Proprierties, WordWrap for false and Scrollbars to Both.

I can somehow do this?

Sorry for my bad english, thanks !

Follow my Code

```
public Visualization(mFile file, string title)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    try
    {
        labelTitle.Text = $"{title} | {file.fileName}";
        
        RichTextBoxVisualization.Text = File.ReadAllText(file.myPathFile);                                                                                                
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show($"Error on read : {ex.Message}", "Erro!");
        Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: We're going to need to see some code. Can you post code you are using to load a file to the `RichTexBox`? Is this regular text file or a file in the `RTF` format?

Comment: Post the code you use to scroll the Control to a position. Loading a file doesn't cause the Control (or Notepad) to scroll anywhere.

Comment: Is a Regular text file in txt format @Jackdaw

Comment: I'm Setting the Scrolls property to ScrollBars.Both on the Property box @Jimi

Comment: That Property is used to determine what scrollbars are visible. When you load a file, the Control doesn't scroll anywhere. You mean, when you manually scroll the Control, dragging the horizontal ScrollBar, it doesn't scroll to the end of the longest line if spaces are present. -- I mean, explain that better in your question, otherwise people may not get it. How you load a file is unrelated.